# Problem with the SVD of a large complex matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I have a fat and complex matrix $H$ on which I would like to perform an SVD.

Because of its size, I'm forced to using a trick based on the computation of a covariance matrix.

$H H^\dagger = U S V^\dagger V S U^\dagger = U S² U^\dagger$
and then I find each singular vector $\mathbf{v_k}$ in $V$ with
$\mathbf{v_k} = \frac{1}{s_k} U^\dagger \mathbf{h_k}$

The problem is, this approach seems only valid for a real matrix and I can't figure out why when looking at the math. Here is a simple matlab proof of concept.

```
H = randn(3,5);
% H = randn(3,5) + 1j*randn(3,5);

Hc = H*H';
[U,S] = eig(Hc);
U = fliplr(U);
S = sqrt(flipud(diag(S)));
V = bsxfun(@times,U'*H,1./S).';

[Ua,Sa,Va] = svd(H,'econ'); % for comparison
```

Comment: Whats the point of fliplr and flipud here?

Comment: it's to get the descending order convention of the SVD (eig seems to be ascending here)

Comment: Also, why are you using bsxfun instead of taking `V = (U'*H)./S`?

Comment: `sqrt(flipud(diag(S)))` is not a diagonal matrix; if you want the diagonal matrix with the entries reversed, you'll have to fliplr as well

Comment: It's just an habit when working with diagonal matrices, it makes the computation faster sometimes

Comment: $S$ was already a diagonal matrix, using diag again extract the diagonal. Then the order is reversed and I'm applying the square root

Comment: okay I'm all caught up, thanks very much for clarifying.

Comment: I should have used a more explicit code commenting in the first place, sorry about that

Comment: Really I shouldn't have been focusing on the code so much anyway in retrospect

Comment: In fact, the problem with this approach really seems to be the math.  We should be taking 
$$
\mathbf v_k = \frac{1}{s_k} H^\dagger \mathbf u_k.
$$
If you like, I could put an answer together deriving that.

Comment: If the approach really does work in the real case, then I suspect that you can fix your code by using a conjugate-transpose rather than an entrywise transpose in that last step, as in `V = bsxfun(@times,U'*H,1./S)'`

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for computing $V$ is incorrect.  Note that (assuming $H$ has full rank, $S$ and $U$ are square, $S$ diagonal and $U$ unitary)
$$
H = U S V^\dagger \implies H^\dagger = V S U^\dagger\implies
H^\dagger (SU^\dagger)^{-1} = V \implies\\
V = H^\dagger U S^{-1}.
$$
So, you can find $V$ with `V = bsxfun(@times,H'*U,1./S)`.

Comment: thank you very much, it was a much more basic mistake than I anticipated.